# Which array element is the first?

Tags: arrays, language-agnostic, documentation, terminology, conventions

A few times during discussion about programming, I reached a misunderstanding, caused by different views on how consecutive zero-based array elements are referred to using ordinal numerals. There seem to be two views on that:

```
a[0] = "first";
a[1] = "second";
a[2] = "third;
```

vs:

```
a[0] = "zeroth";
a[1] = "first";
a[2] = "second";
```

I always preferred the first, knowing that "n-th" element is "element of index n-1". But I was surprised how many people found that counter-intuitive and used the latter version.

Is one of those conventions more correct than the other? Which should I use during discussion or documentation to avoid misunderstanding?

Comment: the *first item* can be accessed by the *zero[th] index*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the English meaning of the word "[first](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/first)" is unambiguous, and refers to the initial element of a sequence. Having "first" refer to the successor of the initial element is just wrong.

In cases where there might be confusion, I would say "the third element, at index 2".

Answer (score 5):

The element index is pretty much **language-dependent** (e.g. C: 0, Lua: 1), whereas the fifth element *is* the fifth element, it's just the index that may be different ;)

I guess that's way too diffuse an answer...

Comment: There's no confusion when the array's 1-based :).

Comment: I haven't talked about confusion. Just a slight difference :). One has to *know* and *understand* the peculiarities of the languages one uses. ;)

Answer (score 3):

In some languages, such as Pascal, you can specify the range of indexes explicitly. i.e.

```
var stuff : array[-3..3] of integer;
```

`stuff[-3]` is still the first element in the array, not the negative third.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone saying 'zeroth' must not really believe in zero-based indexing.

Comment: Math often chooses 0-based indices instead of 1-based.  The choice is more arbitrary in math than in programming: coders almost always use the built-in language feature/standard library, whereas in math you usually define your terms from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The first is the one which is first taken from the stack.